# what does "'We're in the stickiest situation since Sticky the Stick Insect got stuck on a sticky bun."

Tags: meaning

What does

> We're in the stickiest situation since Sticky the Stick Insect got
>   stuck on a sticky bun.

mean in plain english?

Comment: It means we're in trouble, deep doo-doo, up to our necks in alligators, up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: Alligators like crocodiles or something ?

Comment: Yes, alligators are like crocodiles.

Comment: It means you're in a very precarious position that could end up quite badly if you're not careful.

Comment: A "sticky situation" is a possibly-unfortunate occurrence, in which you might get stuck, i.e., one you might not be able to disengage from easily. I'm assuming the other "sticky" references are clear.

Comment: Someone texted me but I didn't know how to reply it since I'm not sure what he means, all I know is that he's in difficult situation

Comment: Crocodiles like alligators, but I don't think that alligators like crocodiles.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help guys, I think we can just let Crocodiles & Alligators find their own way. The look same anyway. Tell me if they bother you, I'll slap those crocodile and alligator.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Perhaps it's neither reptile, but rather a troll. On that possibility, I'm deleting my comments.  Never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A situation that is *sticky* is one that is difficult to extricate oneself from, just as it is sometimes difficult, in a literal sense, to put down a piece of paper with adhesive on it.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sticky) defines *sticky* as "difficult" or "problematic"--in other words, such a situation is not only not easy to extricate oneself from, it is also a negative experience.

All of the rest is simply to emphasize the degree of stickiness--that is, this is not a *slightly* sticky situation, it is an *extremely* sticky situation.